# EF Core database connection required db user configuration

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm facing an issue where I have a db user that already existed with which I can connect to the db from my dotnet app using a connection string. I have recently created a new db login and user but whatever the roles I give to it, even sysadmin I cannot get the connection to work using my dotnet app.

I can however connect to the db using this new user and execute queries via Azure Data Studio. The only error I get from my app is "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Failed to open  session for user ...". What did I miss during the configuration ?

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Server instance's Error Log yet? If there are any Error 18456 messages check their `State` number and compare it/them against hose listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16) to determine the actual problem.